# Gaussian reduction of matrices

Tags: math-mode, matrices, arrays

I have to show a Gaussian reduction in an assignment, and I was wondering what the more space-efficient and neatest way of expressing this is.  I thought about using `\begin{smallmatrix}` (it's only a 2x2 matrix) and arrays, but I'm wondering if perhaps there is a better way.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`gauss` package](//ctan.org/pkg/gauss) is specifically designed for this purpose and allows for typesetting even large matrices and the associated Gaussian elimination (or reduction).

Here is a fairly elementary example of Gaussian (or Gauss-Jordan) elimination on a 2x2 matrix:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gauss,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  & \begin{gmatrix}[p]
      1 & 2 \\
      3 & 4
      \rowops
      \add[-3]{0}{1}
    \end{gmatrix} \\
  \Rightarrow & \begin{gmatrix}[p]
      1 & 2 \\
      0 & -2
      \rowops
      \mult{1}{\scriptstyle\cdot-\frac{1}{2}}
    \end{gmatrix} \\
  \Rightarrow & \begin{gmatrix}[p]
      1 & 2 \\
      0 & 1
      \rowops
      \add[-2]{1}{0}
    \end{gmatrix} \\
  \Rightarrow & \begin{gmatrix}[p]
      1 & 0 \\
      0 & 1
    \end{gmatrix}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Matrices using the `gauss` package are typeset within a `gmatrix` environment (an optional parameter specifies the delimiters), while elementary row operations are specified using `\mult`, `\add`, or `\swap`. See the [`gauss` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/gauss) for more information and refinements.

[`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provided the `align*` environment, although it was not necessary; a regular `array` would also have worked.

Comment: I think there is a calculation mistake! Shouldn't the (2, 2) element in the second matrix be -2? Accordingly, the subsequent calculations will change.

Comment: @Ashirwad: Thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 3):

read https://archiv.dante.de/DTK/PDF/komoedie_2002_3.pdf, pages 34--40 for an introduction into the package `gauss`. The examples should be self explanatory.