# Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to plot the below figure. What must I do in Latex?

Is there an Editor as LaTable to design this figure?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can help http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142618/83280

Comment: The TikZ package does general graphics.  See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36474/gaussian-reduction-of-matrices

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, the left figure.

I hope you will try to understand the commented code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, patterns, arrows.meta, bending}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[bend, length=5pt]}]

%Outer square
\node[minimum size=2cm, draw, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (A) {};

%Dashed square
\node[minimum size=1cm, draw, pattern = north west lines, draw, anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (a) {};

%North trapezium
\filldraw[fill=blue!15, line join=bevel] (A.north west)-|(a.north east)--(a.north west)--cycle;

%blue vertical line and label
\draw[line width=2mm, blue!30] (a.north west)--(a.south west) node[below, black]{$k$};

%two white little squares
\node[draw, fill=white, minimum size=2mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (a.north west)(b1) {};

\node[draw, fill=white, minimum size=2mm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at ([yshift=-7mm]a.north west) (b2) {};

%dashed lines and labels
\draw[dashed] (b1)--(b1-|A.west) node [left] (k) {$k$};

\draw[dashed] (b2)--(b2-|A.west) node [left] (r) {$\overline{r}$};

%Big 0 at dashed lines area center
\path (k)-- node[font=\Large] {$0$} (b2);

%Curved line
\path (k.west) edge[<->, bend right=45] (r.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, Please tell me you design this figure by a editors or you write these codes line by line?

Comment: @Nima Quite certainly Ignasi's written the code by hand. There are some tools that can generate code for e.g. (see [What You See is What You Get (WYSIWYG) for PGF/TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24235) and [What GUI applications are there to assist in generating graphics for TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26972)&lq=1), though the code produced by such programs is often messy and not very flexible.

Comment: @Nima I wrote it by hand. Long time ago I tested (2 min) some editor but, for me, it's faster and funnier without it.