# Annotating vertical relations with multiline equations

Tags: arrows, annotations

It would be nice to be able to create something like this in LaTeX:

[image]

So basically, the idea is to write relations vertically, have them be extensible, and be able to annotate them with possibly multiple lines of qualification.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

---

My question is different from the linked question in that Gaussian reduction is just an example of why you might want such a thing. I am specifically looking for a way of doing annotated extensible vertical relations; properly speaking, this has nothing to do with matrices.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gaussian reduction of matrices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36474/gaussian-reduction-of-matrices)

Comment: please provide, what you try so far ... if matrices is not an issue, then at least help us to help you and provide code for them.  we are not service "do-it-for-me! by the way, if you put matrices in some picture environment, than you can draw relation between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With correct computations `;-)`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newcommand{\GE}[1]{%
  \qquad\left\Updownarrow\;
  \begin{aligned}#1\end{aligned}%
  \right.%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|ccc@{}}
  3 & -2 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 &  0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 &  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
\\
&\GE{
  R_3 & \leftrightarrow R_1 \\
  R_2 & \leftrightarrow R_1
}
\\
&\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|ccc@{}}
1 &  0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 &  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
3 & -2 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\\
&\GE{
  R_3 & \coloneqq R_2-3R_1 \\
  R_3 & \coloneqq R_3+2R_1
}
\\
&\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|ccc@{}}
1 & 0 &  2 & 0 &  1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 &  0 & 0 &  0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & 1 & -3 & 2
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```